# How to convert HSV when some variable over range

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hsv

The title may not declare, for example:
Here is an HSV(321, 120, 60), the saturation is over range (0-100), how to correct to normal range ?

Please show the convert algorithm, thanks.

Comment: How did you get such values in the first place? Please show your image and your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Different applications use different scales for HSV.

For example gimp uses H = 0-360, S = 0-100 and V = 0-100.

But OpenCV uses H: 0-179, S: 0-255, V: 0-255.

So it is important to know application max and min values to convert it correctly.